# Find best correlation between two vectors of data

Tags: r

I am trying to find the best correlation (i.e. highest r squared value) between two lists of data within a specified range (i.e. find the range of 'x' values that have the best correlation with their corresponding 'y' values). Basically I am looking for the linear range in the data. This is what I have so far:

```
 #Example data - actually have a much more complicated data set
    x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    y <- c(0.25,1.5,3,4,5,6,6.5,7,7.5)
    data.range <- 0 #create a new variable which will contain the 
    r.sq <- 0
    for (i in 1:length(x)) {
      r.sq[i] <- round(cor(x[i:(i+5)], y[i:(i+5)],4)
      data.range[i] <- paste(x[i], x[i+5], sep = " - ")
      output <- data.frame(na.omit(cbind(data.range, r.sq)))
    }
#Example read out
head(output)
  data.range    r.sq
  1 - 6         0.9963
  2 - 7         0.9906
  3 - 8         0.9885
  4 - 9         0.9839
```

Here, I have the output set to give me a dataframe containing the ranges of 'x' data that are being correlated with the associated 'y', and the cor() value corresponding to that range of 'x' data. Right now, I am projecting the correlation between 'x' and 'y' using 5 points (hence the i+5), but in the end I don't want to have to define the "5" as the linear range may span 6 or 8 points. So I want to do all possible correlations of 'x' and 'y' and result a list of the ranges of data (data.range) with the corresponding cor() value (r.sq).

```
data.range     r.sq        
1 - 4          0.9999
1 - 5          0.9808
1 - 6          0.9805
1 - 7          etc...
1 - 8
1 - 9
2 - 5
2 - 6
2 - 7
2 - 8
etc....
```

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: you're already using a loop, why not use a nested loop for the second value in the range?

Comment: I feel like that's the solution, but I can't seem to make the code work. I'm pretty new to R, would you mind giving me an idea of how it would look?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You have an `i` loop that goes from 1 to the `length(x)`. So:

```
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    for (j in desired_start:desired_finish) {
        r.sq[i] <- cor(x[i:j], y[i:j], n)
```

You get the rest. There are more ways to do this, but if you're new this is a really nice start and you seem to have a nice grasp on loops. This will loop through `i` first and capture each possible value of `j` for each `i`

Comment: Okay, the question now is how to define the desired start and finish. In the code above, I use `cor(cor(x[i:(i+5)], y[i:(i+5)]`, giving me 1 - 6, 2 - 7, 3 - 8. What I want is for the first loop to cycle through 1 - 2, 1 - 3, 1 - 4, etc... then with the second loop, I want to cycle through 2 - 4, 2 - 5, 2 - 6, etc... and then 3 - 6, 3 - 7, 3 - 8, etc...  I can't use `for (j in seq(1, length(x):length(x))` because I get the error "Numerical expression has ## elements: only the first used." - Am I trying to do this in the wrong way? Is there a way to do with with `apply`? Thanks! @jwells